# Timed script not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google script that I would like to run automatically every weekday at 8:11 am.  I have set my time zones to make sure that everything is correct, but it never seems to work correctly. I am still weak at scripting.  Does anyone see where I might have error in this script?

```
function myFunction(){
try {
var d = new Date();
if (d.getDay() == 6 || d.getDay() == 0) return;
if (d.getHours() != 08 && d.getMinutes() != 11) return;  // This will stop the script from running unless it is 8:11am
} catch (e) {
MailApp.sendEmail("pthompson@ucc.on.ca", "Error report", e.message);
}
}
```

Thank you,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

To run a function based on time, setup a project trigger (under Resources tab) with the Event "Time-driven". You can even setup a notification.

If you wanted to manage this trigger programmatically you could do something like this:

```
function createTimeTrigger() {

  // Once a day at 8AM, near minute 11 for function 'writeSomething()'
  var dailyHourNearMinute = ScriptApp.newTrigger("writeSomething")
      .timeBased()
      .everyDays(1)
      .atHour(8)
      .nearMinute(11)
      .create();
}
```

You will notice that this creates a trigger for you that can be viewed under 'Current project's triggers'. It will say between 8AM-9AM. As far as google time events, they work well at getting it within the hour but not on the exact minute. The load in the system can also throw this off. So, the best you can really plan for is, between 8AM - 9AM.

Comment: Hi.  I had a look at that, but what if I want to have it run specifically at 8:11 am daily?  There doesn't seem to be an option for that.

Comment: I have added my response to the answer.

Comment: Silly question, but ss 'writeSomething()' just an random name?

Comment: Yes. Just a random function I created so I could verify how the time triggers work. Just replace it with the function name of your choice.

Comment: Hi.  I added what you wrote to my code.  When I go to look at my project's triggers, it tells me that "The selected function can not be found".  I put it in the first lines of my code.  Any idea why it might be giving me this error?  Thank you.  Paul

Comment: Make sure the function you tell it matches exactly with the function name. Example: `function writeSomething()` then you should put `ScriptApp.newTrigger("writeSomething")`.

Comment: Hi @nwill001.  I double checked, and this is what I have.  I cut and pasted the example:  `function createTimeTrigger() {

  // Once a day at 8AM, near minute 11 for function 'Announcements()'
  var dailyHourNearMinute = ScriptApp.newTrigger("Announcements")
      .timeBased()
      .everyDays(1)
     .atHour(8)
      .nearMinute(11)
      .create();
}`

Comment: Ok. So I assume you have another function called Announcements() that you are intending to be ran with this trigger. Make sure you run this createTimeTrigger function so it creates a trigger for your Announcements function. Also, make sure to run the Announcements function at least once manually to make sure all the permissions are good and it does what you intend.

Comment: Hi @nwill001.  I do not have another function called announcements.  Is that possible why I am getting the error?  The only other function that is currently in my script is a one labeled `function onFormSubmit(e) {`

Comment: A trigger is used to run a function. You need to have a valid function that you wish to be ran with this timed event. Please remember to mark best answer if you feel it best answered your question.